# Microsoft Visual Studio. Registers

Tags: visual-studio, x86, visual-studio-debugging, cpu-registers

When I am debugging in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 my "Registers" window shows no data available. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Data can't be inspected in the debugger unless the process is paused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sneftel stated, you cannot inspect data in the debugger unless you break the execution of the process. During execution, things would be changing far too quickly for any data display to be meaningful.

You can use the "Pause" button in the toolbar to break execution, and then you will see everything in the debugger: the current source line, the contents of registers, your "watch" variables, the full contents of memory in the "Memory" window, etc.

You can also set a breakpoint on a particular line of code, and then execution will break once that point is reached.

Once paused, you can then *single-step* through your program's code. This means that one line of code (the very next one) will be executed, and then the program will break again so that you can see everything in the debugger. This is an *excellent* troubleshooting technique—one that you should be well-acquainted with. In fact, I recommend that you single-step through every line of code that you write, just to make sure that it works correctly. You can also modify the contents of registers and variables (or, really, any location in memory) while you are single-stepping, giving yourself a way to test potential bug fixes or even introduce bugs (e.g., invalid input) to see how your code handles them. The default keyboard shortcut for single-step is <kbd>F11</kbd>.

You'll find more information about using the debugger, and the available keyboard shortcuts, [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx). As you can see, that article confirms my answer:

> Most debugger features, such as viewing variable values in the Locals window or evaluating expressions in the Watch window, are available only while the debugger is paused (also called break mode). When the debugger is paused, your app state is suspended while functions, variables, and objects remain in memory. While in break mode, you can examine the elements' positions and states to look for violations or bugs.

(Edit-and-continue is not available in assembly projects. You will need to stop execution and rebuild if you want to make changes to your code.)

Comment: I get "No data available on code in data space.   This used to work in VS2015 when one had code in data space.  Doesn't seem to work with VS2017/VS2019.    One might not like the idea of code in data space, but it has worked for 25 years and still works if you don't single step.  Any hints on how to enable this?

Comment: I haven't seen that, @Ira. This worked for me in VS 2017, I'm pretty sure. I haven't updated to 2019 yet.

Answer (score 2):

For those with the "No data available" message, you can right click in the Registers window and choose what you want to see (UC, MMX, SSE, etc). It seems like by default there's nothing selected in Visual Studio 2019. At least, on mine there was nothing selected.